# Execute multiple processes using bash

Tags: linux, bash, process

I want to run multiple processes in parallel using bash. I did the following:

`./proc sth1 & ./proc sth2 & ./proc sth3 & ... & ./proc sthN &`

The problem with the above is that it immediately ends. So if I do:
`time (./proc sth1 &  ... & ./proc sthN &)` I get back `0`.

I want to run the above command but I want it to stop when the last process has finished.
So if `./proc sthX` takes 10 seconds while all the other processes take 1 second. I want to wait for 10 seconds till the above command returns. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just call `wait` at the end. Quoting bash manual [Job control builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Job-Control-Builtins):

> `wait [jobspec or pid ...]`
>
> Wait until the child process specified by each process ID pid or job specification jobspec exits and return the exit status of the last command waited for. If a job spec is given, all processes in the job are waited for. **If no arguments are given, all currently active child processes are waited for,** and the return status is zero. If neither jobspec nor pid specifies an active child process of the shell, the return status is 127.

An example:

```
#!/bin/bash
function test {
    time=$(( RANDOM % 10 ))
    echo "Sleeping for $time"
    sleep "$time"
    echo "Slept for $time"
}

time (
    test & test & test & test & test & test &
    wait
    echo "Finished all."
)
```

Answer (score 1):

`wait` is designed for this :

```
./proc sth1 & ./proc sth2 & ./proc sth3 & ... & ./proc sthN &
 wait
```

Some doc :

```
$ LANG=C help wait
wait: wait [id]
    Wait for job completion and return exit status.

    Waits for the process identified by ID, which may be a process ID or a
    job specification, and reports its termination status.  If ID is not
    given, waits for all currently active child processes, and the return
    status is zero.  If ID is a a job specification, waits for all processes
    in the job's pipeline.

    Exit Status:
    Returns the
```

status of ID; fails if ID is invalid or an invalid option is
    given.

Another solution is to get all pids and put a `wait` for all of these pids.

Answer (score 0):

Another example to use `wait` with a list of jobs :

```
nbf=0
jobs -p|while read -r; do
    wait $REPLY || (( nbf++ ))
done
echo "$nbf jobs ended with failure" >&2
```

Answer (score 0):

While "wait and & combination" might be sufficient, I found that it's not what I want most of the time. What I want is that return-code would indicate failure in case any command fails by default. So I created a small utility called `par`:

https://github.com/k-bx/par